# If a question has one tag that I've watched and another tag that I've ignored, how is it displayed?

Tags: support, tags, questions, user-interface

If there is a question with multiple tags, of which I am ignoring one (should be faded) and watching another (should be made more visible), how will it be displayed for me?

What if I am hiding ignored tags?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey  Actually, asking the question has so far required more time than just experimenting would have, as I first went through the faqs to see if these features were explained anywhere (couldn't find it) and then searched for questions with the tags "tag", "watch", and "ignore".  It was through these searches that I learned that hiding ignored tags was a thing, since I hadn't known that before.  So, I could have just  experimented, but I would have been missing that variable.  And that is part of why I think asking the question is worthwhile, even if it is not easier.

Comment: Ideally it will attract answers from people who know more about the system than I do, or than I could have even discovered by experimentation, and will create a record of a question asked and answered to help future users.  [Note that above should say with the _keywords_ "tag", "watch", and "ignore" - my edit timed out.]

Comment: I’m still not sure what more of an answer you’re looking for than what you could discover yourself. Like, I’m not saying it’s a bad question or anything but again, it’s not like it takes hours of hard work to find the answer. You could even self-answer with what you’ve discovered and that would be good. I’m just finding it hard to see this as anything more than “do this very simple task for me”.

Comment: From MSE (watched used to be called favorite): [What happens if a question is both tagged with favorite and ignored tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116337) (Questions can't be closed as dupes cross-site, but our answer below has pictures!)

Comment: That it used to be called something else is useful, thank you.  It appears that this is  duplicate question.

Comment: I attempted to vote to close as a duplicate, using the cite from Someone_Evil.  The response was "The duplicate question must exist on Role-playing Games Meta Stack Exchange" and would not let me select vote to close.  I have flagged for mod attention.

Comment: @Kirt Questions can't be closed as dupes cross site (can you imagine the mess it would cause?). We're fine with having out own copy (many users don't read/search MSE), so nothing to worry about. Plus TM's answer below has a picture showing it off!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Current as of January 28, 2022

Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:

[image]

#### Obsolete: January 27, 2022

Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:

[image]

The peepee tag is back. Subject to change again, users are pushing back against this design as well ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375638/674198) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375639/674198)).

#### Obsolete: January 26, 2022

Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:

[image]

It has returned to the original version, with votes/answers/views being a bit different.

#### Obsolete: January 25, 2022

Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:

[image]

This one existed for less than a day, it was killed by [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375506/674198).

#### Obsolete

In this image I have the four possible states in this order: Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:
[image]

A post with a watched tag and an ingored tag gets greyed out by ignore and gets the highlighting for watched. This can be verified with no more than two clicks of the mouse.

If you have ignored a tag and set to hide questions with that tag, then it seems the question does not appear at all, even if it is also tagged with a tag you are watching.

Comment: Nice. Were you able to test what happens if the user has ignored tags set to be hidden entirely?

Comment: @V2Blast   I did - questions with a tag that has been hidden simply do not appear, irrespective of them having another tag that is watched.   In my opinion this is an important interaction that would be useful to state up front.

Comment: @Kirt: Cool, that's what I'd expect to happen.