# What does it mean when a question is highlighted yellow?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

I've been part of the RPG SE community for a few months now I think, but I'm still learning the ropes and I consider myself new. This is my first time asking on meta and I apologize in advance if I made any mistakes while asking this question.

When browsing on mobile, I noticed a few questions are highlighted as yellow. What does this mean?
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: See here: [If a question has one tag that I've watched and another tag that I've ignored, how is it displayed?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11206)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question, which is asking what happens when a question has watched tags and ignored tags at the same time. This is just asking why a question is highlighted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the image below, I have examples of the four possible highlight states for a question in this order - Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched:

[image: Examples of highlighting based on tag status: Watched and Ignored, Ignored, Default, Watched]

You probably have the [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) tag set to watched - or, as Someone_Evil's comment points out, you may have [homebrew-review](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew-review) set to watched, which is why you haven't noticed it until now, as it is a fairly rare tag.

Comment: Or [homebrew-review] which would explain why they haven't noticed it that much

Comment: I do have dnd-5e set to watched, thank you for the answer!